# Angular: how to manage a single checked box in a *ngFor

Tags: angular, checkbox

Hi there I've displayed a list of items with a checkbox in it.

I want the user to able to click this checkbox for only one of the item. It will uncheck the previously checked checkbox.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items>
 <td>
    <input type="checkbox value = "{{ item[i] }}">
  </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried everything I knew but I cant make it. If I check a box, the other one will remain checked.

1- Is it possible to do what I want? 
2- How can I do?

Comment: It's possible with code, but I would recommend using radio buttons if only one option can be selected

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use `radio` button in this case.

But you can programmatically control the behaviour of `checkbox` so only one checkbox is selected at a time.

You can look out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzv9tb), this may helps you

Template file

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li>
      <input 
         type="checkbox" 
        [value]="item.value"
        [checked]="item.isChecked"
        (change)="onChange($event);"
        > {{item.label}}
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Class file:

maintain a  isChecked property in `item` list and bind it to check `attribute` in `input` element, then bind `change` event on input element whenever use change the change handler i.e `onChange` will trigger, then iterate on item and reinit the `isChecked` property expect currently check item.

```
items = [
      {'label': 'A', 'value': 'A', isChecked: false},
      {'label': 'B', 'value': 'B', isChecked: false},
      {'label': 'C', 'value': 'C', isChecked: false},
      {'label': 'D', 'value': 'D', isChecked: false},
      {'label': 'E', 'value': 'E', isChecked: false},
      {'label': 'F', 'value': 'F', isChecked: false},
      {'label': 'G', 'value': 'G', isChecked: false}
    ]; 

  onChange(event: any) { 
    const {checked, value} = event.target;
    let index = this.items.length;
    while(index--) {
       this.items[index].isChecked = value === this.items[index]['value'];
    }
  }
```